# An inequality concerning the sides of convex quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, inequality

$ABCD$ is a convex quadrilateral such that $ \angle ABC\ge120^{o} , \angle BCD\ge120^{o}$ , then is it true that

$AC+BD>AB+BC+CD$ ?